# Form destroy (OnDestroy) never called when using custom styles? XE7

Tags: delphi

Delphi XE7 - When using custom styles (Project, Options, appearance) OnDestroy never gets called. Using default-native-windows skin-theme, form destroy is called as expected, is this normal? 
If so, what are other alternatives besides OnClose?

Blank project, OnDestroy():

```
procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('destroy called only when not using styles');
end;
```

**Solution and advice:**

When using styles (see @andreas advice): `onDestroy()` is not a good place to put code, since application termination will not wait for all code to finish, some code might be executed but there is a chance not all.

Comment: You could override the form's destructor.

Comment: Still, both calls -default and overrided destroy- get called only if not using custom styles, someone says that using custom styles "wreak havoc"?...

Comment: I generally advice against using VCL styles.

Comment: Yeap, for now i'll do the clean up stuff in the `onclose()` of the main form...

Comment: I can not reproduce with XE7 and `Aqua Graphite` style. Which style are you using?

Comment: Any of the 20+ themes listed, I did a test on a blank project, also Debug and Release, 32 and 64 bit, same behaviour all, I'm using Win7 64 bit, XE7

`ShowMessage('destroy called only when not using styles');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OnDestroy` event is called irrespective of whether styles are used or not, when the form is in the process of being destroyed. You can confirm it by putting a break point on the `ShowMessage()` line (works of course only when running under the debugger) or by adding a call to `Beep()` (assuming your sound system is OK).

When the main form is destroyed, the program starts to prepare for termination. The call to `ShowMessage()` makes a furious attempt to show the message box but the process is already going down. The message box can even be seen briefly as a flash, in the case of not succeeding in staying visible. It is close to a miracle that the message box shows up in some OS's under any conditions.

Anyway, The best place to show any messages at the end, is in either `OnCloseQuery()` or `OnClose()` events. The `OnDestroy()` event is only meant to clean up any resources aquired in the `OnCreate()` event.

Comment: Yes, I confirm, it breaks when putting a break point, also the dialog flashing (but not waiting). The problem was not a dialog showing up or not, but some records in a db not getting a chance to update before termination. Leaving styles aside, events and code execution works as expected.

Comment: So why do you not want to use `OnCloseQuery()` and / or `OnClose()` events, as you ruled `OnClose()` out in your question? Those are the events mostly used to assure data is stored before terminating.

Comment: I needed the final method as in `onDestroy()` for all 5 forms in my app (each one doing some clean up and settings saving). On the main form using `onClose()` works ok (put clean up code here no problem, it works as `onDestroy()`), but on secondary forms `onClose()` works as in `Hide()` or minimize, right?

Comment: *...each one doing some clean up and settings saving…* the `OnClose` event is exactly for that purpose. As a final step you set the `Action: TCloseAction` parameter to which ever you want/need to: `caNone`, `caHide`, `caFree` or `caMinimize`. If you are about to close the application `caFree` seems like a good candidate. Check the docs for `TCloseEvent`